# Show that $L$ is trivial if and only if $L$ and its dual $L^∗$ admit non-trivial global sections.

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

> Let $L$ be a holomorphic line bundle on a compact connected complex manifold $X$. Show that $L$ is trivial if and only if $L$ and its dual $L^∗$ admit non-trivial global sections. (Hint: Use the non-trivial sections to construct a non-trivial section of $\mathcal{O} \cong L \otimes L^∗$.)

If we first assume that $L$ is trivial, then we can fix any non-zero $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and consider a section $s:X \to L$ for which $s(p)=(p,v)$ and this gives a non-trivial global section. Also for a section $t:X \to L^*$ we can fix non-zero $w \in L^*$ which means that $t(p) = (p,w)$ is also non-trivial global section.

Assume then that $L$ and $L^*$ admit non-trivial global sections say $s \in \Gamma(X,L)$ and $t \in \Gamma(X, L^*)$. Now I'm confused about this since I need to show that $L$ is trivial, but we know that a line bundle is trivial if and only if it has a nowhere zero section so $s$ being one would immediatley imply that $L$ is trivial. What am I not understanding here?

Comment: Note that a non-trivial section is just a section which is not the zero section. In particular, $s$ is not necessarily a nowhere-zero section, it could have zeroes.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a duplicate of the linked question? The linked question deals with cohomology and this does not.

Comment: $H^0(X, L) = \Gamma(X, L)$ is the space of sections of $L$. Requiring $L$ to have a non-trivial section is therefore equivalent to $H^0(X, L) \neq 0$. So your question can be rephrased as follows: $L$ is trivial if and only if $H^0(X, L) \neq 0$ and $H^0(X, L^*) \neq 0$. That is, $H^0(X, L)$ and $H^0(X, L^*)$ cannot both be non-trivial unless $L$ is trivial.

Comment: Okay I can see this. I would still be interested in the case in which the hint refers to where we construct a non-trivial section of $L \otimes L^*$ using the map $$H^0(X, L) \otimes H^0(X, L^*) \to H^0(X, L \otimes L^*).$$ @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: Did you look at the answer to the linked question? That's exactly how the argument proceeds.

Comment: I did, but I'm bit confused with the notation. What is the subscript $x$ denoting, Is it a germ when you use $f_x$ and the tangent space when you use $\mathcal{L}_x$? @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: $\mathcal{L}_x$ denotes the fiber of $\mathcal{L}$ over the point $x$, while $f_x$ denotes the value of the section $f$ at the point $x$, i.e. $f_x \in \mathcal{L}_x$.